# Removing the user with no password which is there in sudoers

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have a user called **ec2-user** and by this user I am getting connected to my EC2 instance by the help of the pem file I am able to connect to the machine,

Now I have added this user to the sudoers list by this command:

```
echo 'ec2-user ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

This command executed successfully but after that when ever I want to do **sudo** its asking for password, when there is no password on the ec2-user.

Now, I have some of the questions:

1. If this is the wrong way, why Linux allows it to complete the command?
2. If this is right, then how to give the password?
3. If this I did in wrong way, how can I come back to my normal situation?

Thanks all

Comment: Try: `ec2-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` (and use `visudo` to edit your sudoers file)

Comment: In order to do **visudo** I have to place the password,and I dont have any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is the wrong way, why Linux allows it to complete the command?

No point in blaming Linux, It assumes that you have password set for an user.

> If this is right, then how to give the password?

No, you can't provide a pasword because there is no pasword

> If this I did in wrong way, how can I come back to my normal
>   situation?

Only way out is to boot the machine in single user mode and undo your changes. **Unfortunately**, you cannot boot an EC2 instnace into single user mode. Check with Amazon support whether they can help you with that.

You are pretty have run out of options. Create a new instance and then copy over your data by attaching EBS volume of this instance.

Comment: Great way of explaining the things bro, but I am not satisfied with the answer for point no 1, why can't I blame an OS, obviously if the way I am doing is wrong, OS should intimate me, otherwise should behave the same as I expect it to be, and for me neither of the things are working, and may be for you, I am wrong but I think, if this is something that can not be brought back, Linux has to display a Prompt saying you are adding a user in sudoers list without the password, be careful, or something like that....
:)

Comment: @ankurverma, I cannot comment on your thoughts. If you think it is a worthwhile solution, then please raise this issue on Linux Kernel Mailing List where developers who write linux kernel will be able to port this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Amazon Linux AMI. For this AMI, by default the only account that can log in remotely using SSH is ec2-user. Also by default, password authentication is disabled to prevent brute-force password attacks. You must provide your key pair to the instance at launch, as you have already done. **Please note that ec2-user has sudo privileges by default**. When you do sudo, you don't have to enter any password. When you changed the sudoers file manually, you kind of changed the setting to require the password for any sudo operation by user ec2-user. Sorry that I don't know a easy way to get back to normal. I would suggest launching a new AMI instance and terminating your old one.